Unix socket in /tmp turns into directory on reboot
I run an Ubuntu based server on raspi (6.5.0-1015-raspi #18-Ubuntu). On this system, I have knxd running, exposing a KNX bus to my server, and then Home Asssitant in a docker container. knxd and docker are configured as systemctl services.
knxd is configured to create a UNIX domain socket in /tmp/eib, with the command line argument -u /tmp/eib. This works when I start the service, e.g. using systemctl start, once the system is running.
However after reboot, there's a directory in /tmp/eib, owned by root:root, which blocks knxd from creating its domain socket. knxd then (understandably) crashes on start. When I manually remove the directory with sudo rm -rf /tmp/eib, and then systemctl restart knxd, knxd manages to create the correct socket and start up successfully.
# after reboot. With this in place, knxd crashes on startup.
$ ll -d /tmp/eib
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 27 09:33 /tmp/eib/
# If I manually remove the file...
$ sudo rm -rf /tmp/eib
$ sudo systemctl restart knxd
# ... wait a bit ...
# ... then knxd comes up successfully and creates the correct file+permissions
$ ll -d /tmp/eib
srwxr-xr-x 1 knxd knxd 0 Apr 27 09:39 /tmp/eib=
# now knxd and everything depending on it works fine

How do I debug who's creating this file? How do I set things up such that knxd comes up successfully after a reboot?

knxd github repository at https://github.com/knxd/knxd mentions where the socket is created:
"If you use Debian Jessie or another systemd-based distribution, /lib/systemd/system/knxd.socket is used to open the "standard" sockets on which knxd listens to clients. You no longer need your old -i or -u options."
It also advises using /run/ instead of /tmp:
"knxd's Unix socket should never have been located in /tmp; the default is now /run/knx. You can add a -u /tmp/eib (or whatever) option if necessary, but it's better to fix the clients."
